# Supress Reminders for Specific Outlook Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Is there a way to supress reminders on Outlook (Windows) for a specific calendar (and that calendar only)?

I often work away, and so I have the city's football team's calendar synced to mine, as any matches have a significant effect on accommodation availability, so it's useful to see that information when planning trips. However, this also means that it sends me a notification every time a match is on, which is something I don't want.

I don't want to supress all notifications as that would stop useful ones from my own calendars.

Comment: Go to that appointment and turn Reminders OFF.

Comment: That's more work than just dismissing the reminder when it comes up.

Comment: That is all that is available to you in Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with John, you can only open the specific calendar event and remove the reminder in Outlook desktop client.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.